# Why was this question migrated to Ask Different?

Tags: discussion, migration, mod-abuse

Why was [Why are there so many 2.1A usb chargers out there?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/279699/why-are-there-so-many-2-1a-usb-chargers-out-there?noredirect=1) Migrated to Ask Different, the Apple stack exchange. Op was not asking about apple products.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/279699/revisions

Comment: Where would you rather migrate it?

Comment: I rather you stop abusing your power and read the rules for migrations in general.

Comment: Please calm down.

Comment: Please stop abusing migrations.

Comment: Next time I see an off-topic question like that, I'm deleting it instead of migrating it.

Comment: Please calm down. Irrational threats like that have no place in civilized conversation. If you feel incapable of handling your job as a mod without extremist threats, resign.

Comment: This is not a threat.  It's my duty to keep EE.SE clean.

Comment: Although I can't agree with the tone used and "abuse of power" statements, I also think this question had no reason to be migrated. This is a purely electronics question. It was, however, a pretty bad question, and certainly deserved some downvotes. But bad questions do not automatically make them off-topic, unfortunately.

Comment: @Passe: Maybe it shouldn't have been migrated, just closed, deleted, and tarred and feathered here.  However, your tone is inappropriate.  In any case, I'm not going to get worked up about how exactly crappy questions are treated.  Good riddance either way.

Comment: I had ten upvotes on an answer I posted to a good question, and then the question got migrated to a site that I am not a user on. I find this rather disheartening. Why can't I keep my rep here if I am not a user on the other site? What did I do wrong?

Comment: @nocomprende  This comment of yours should be posted as a separate question on meta.EE.SE .  It deserves it's own thread.  This is a good question.

Comment: Just passing by, perhaps [FAQ about migration](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) would help...

Comment: @OlinLathrop Sorry, Olin, although I understand your position wrt keeping this site clean, we must acknowledge that "we are not an island", i.e. we are part of a bigger network. The first guideline for migration in the [post linked by AndrewT above](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) reads **"Don't migrate crap!"**. Although, I think the question in it's content is not so idiotic (I agree it could have been formulated much better, though), if we deem it's indeed crap we should not migrate it.

Comment: @OlinLathrop BTW, think if SO began migrating crappy questions about, say, faulty MCU code to our site. We would be swamped in a day with tons of crap!

Comment: @LorenzoDonati you mean like [this one](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/282921/device-tree-binding-can-not-make-work-my-touch-device)? BTW, I'm not saying the question is bad, but it sure looked like they didn't want do deal with it so they dumped it on the neighbour's yard.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Yep! That kind of attitude. Fortunately on SO it is not so common, otherwise, as I said, we would be utterly swamped in no time.

Comment: Somewhat off-topic, but with the new radio directive ("RED") it seems that phone manufacturers will be forced to use standardized chargers. Questions about standardization of chargers within the scope of the radio directive sounds quite on-topic here, particularly if they are about technical specifics. But as far as I know, no technical standards for this have been released yet.

Answer (score 11):

I really think this question should have been disposed of locally, without resorting to migration. Migration was meant as a favour for the question, not a punishment. By migrating a question, you're essentially **promoting** it to another site. It's like saying "Hey guys, look at this insightful question we couldn't fully answer here on EE.SE! I bet your site will benefit from hosting it, and perhaps your users will come up with good answers."

Whenever this question should be *deleted* rather than closed is another topic. I know it won't be useful for me (and I [voted](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/close/133707) to close), but in general it's advised not to delete questions with upvoted answers, since *someone* deemed these useful. There's little harm from having it as long as it's never bumped to the active question list again.

Comment: Useful just to you should not be a valid close reason...

Comment: @Passerby No, a valid close reason would be "primarily opinion-based" (unless we have an authoritative source on why 2.1A limit was chosen). *Useful to someone* is a valid reason not to delete.

Comment: @Passerby  *"Too localized"* is a polite way of saying *"useful just to you"*.

Comment: Funny how they removed too localized as a close reason a long time ago.