# Why was this question migrated to Mechanics.SE?

Tags: discussion, migration, mod-abuse

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/348753/revisions

Was migrated to Motor without any discussion.

It's 100% not about an auto part. Unless you ***wrongly*** think RC models are cars.

Comment: RC models aren't part of electrical engineering either.

Comment: But electrical parts and questions on how to use them ARE.

Comment: I came to ask the same question. I can't even comment or make changes there :|

Comment: This is a question for some RC forum.  If somebody is surprised that a glow plug is a short, he shouldn't be posting the question here.  To summarize: (1) off-topic, (2) insufficient research.

Comment: Your newbie hate and mindless migrations show you shouldn't be posting or moderating here too. To summarize: (1) bad migration of many, (2) insufficient research is not a close reason.

Comment: @MaNyYaCk  You can sign up for the Mechanics.SE stack using the same OpenID.  Once you do that, you should have access to that question.  It may take some time for the things to get reconciled at the other stack.

Comment: The standards on EE.SE shall remain high.  What passerby say is their own business.

Comment: Should have asked me to make changes to question in order to get it into your "High Standard" before migrating.

Comment: And Fyi I was not going to use it for RC Cars, I was going to make my own hot air soldering gun to take out smd components from Old Computer boards I have, because I can't afford one.

Comment: @MaNyYaCk  Not salvageable, I'm afraid.

Comment: It is a discussion site, I understand you wanna keep it clean and good and that may be your job? But discuss first! And patience mate.

Comment: Mind if I ask the question again?

Comment: @MaNyYaCk  I'd suggest that such question would get more traction in our [EE.SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering).  (That's where I take my own borderline questions.)

Comment: @MaNyYaCk While I don't agree with Nick Alexeev in this case, I would like to point out that Stack Exchange is _not_ a discussion site, and that is the main reason for why it has become so popular compared to other technical forums.

Comment: @pipe My bad, I didn't mean to call it a discussion site like some sort of forum, but discussion as in I could have been given feedback regarding the question and what it lacked and Could have certainly improved.

Comment: It's valid to discuss the merits of a migration. But, the comments, particularly from the OP, have devolved to mod-bashing.  This question should now be closed. To salvage the question, this whole chain of comments should be deleted.

Comment: @MaNy: See *"Your newbie hate and mindless migrations"*, and *"as much sense as the fat headed red queen from Alice in Wonderland"*.  It's OK to disagree with a mod action, ask for justification, and to discuss it politely.  But, this is way past that and doesn't belong here.  Since it's the OP doing it, the question should be closed, at least until the whole comment chain is deleted.  Remember, comments aren't for content anyway.

Comment: abusing the close vote with made up rules.  from the same guy that routinely calls arduino users dicks on this website. Stay classy olin.

Comment: Now, this *exact* scenario has already happened a few times, starting with a questionable migration followed by mods being flamed. For example, see https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6069/why-was-this-question-migrated-to-ask-different. So there is probably something deeper to solve here. For example clearly stating the rules of what should be migrated once and for all, and stop barking at each other when we disagree.

Comment: @MaNyYaCk - a platinum wire model engine glowplug is a ~1.5v device and almost certainly NOT what you want for hot air soldering.  Either buy a cheap hot air rework wand (I just a got a temperature controlled portable one for $34 to use on client site visits) or wind a coil of cheaper wire.

Answer (score 6):

Comment by dim:

> [..] I totally disagree with the way Passerby asserts his points, but I also really think this migration wasn't justified. I think it was migrated primarily because the question was deemed bad, not because it was factually off-topic. Migration shouldn't be a way to get rid of bad questions. If it is bad, then we have to close it (and the vote quota is there to ensure enough people agree on this), because it would be bad on any other site anyway. And on the other hand, we wouldn't want the other sites to flood us with bad, distantly-electronics-related questions, would we?

Comment: Mechanics.SE are receiving the question well.  4 upvotes.

Comment: @Nick Sure, because the question was probably not even that bad. I said "[...] was *deemed* bad [...]". "*If* it is bad, we have to close [...]". But I wouldn't have voted to close this myself, actually (hence the reference to the voting process).

Comment: In the context of EESE the question is *both* bad and off-topic.  SE system wide rules are generally that bad questions may not be migrated.  But perhaps what constitutes "bad" is somewhat site dependent.  If the device in question is indeed a *model* engine glowplug, then attempting to use 12v on it is extremely ignorant - but nothing in the question states that it is a model engine glowplug.  A vehicular diesel engine glowplug might more reasonably fit the 12v intent.

Comment: Ignorant, like telling someone asking a question that they basically should know the answer to it prior to asking. I'm glad you were born mowing everything Chris. The rest of us have to ask questions to learn.

Comment: @Passerby the question wasn't about what voltage to use (that would have still been off topic *here*, but at least a fair question *somewhere*).  Instead, it made an ignorantly wrong *assumption* of that in order to ask something else.  FWIW the first model engine glowplug I ever encountered I killed with 12v... because at age ~10 I was *ignorant* of what they needed when I found it in my grandparent's attic.